# How to create foreign key in Sybase database?

Tags: foreign-keys, sybase, create-table

I have two tables in my database that should have connection with PK and FK. Here is example of table 1:

```
RecID(numeric(19,0)) PK CLUSTERED
Name(varchar(100))
Description(varchar(5000))
```

then I want to create second table that will reference to table 1. Here is example of the code I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE table2(
    RefID bigint,
    Status bit,
    Comments varchar(8000),
    FOREIGN KEY fk1(RefID) REFERENCES table1(RecID)
)
```

RefID in table 2 should be the Foreign Key and reference to RecID in table 1. When I run the code above in DBeaver for Sybase here is the error message that I'm getting:

```
SQL Error [102] [37000]: Incorrect syntax near 'fk1'.

  Incorrect syntax near 'fk1'.
```

If anyone can tell me where is my code breaking please let me know. I'm not sure if this is related to DBeaver or my syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [unsupported syntax](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/X80969.htm). You have to use the *CONSTRAINT* clause. Also the types don't match, you should use the same column type as you have used for the other table. The code that works is:

```
CREATE TABLE table2(
    RefID numeric(19,0),
    Status bit,
    Comments varchar(8000),
    constraint fk1 foreign key (RefID) REFERENCES table1(RecID)
)
```